# Save user inputs in R Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

So I wrote an R Shiny app that analyzes student loan information and recommends the best way to pay them down. A lot of people, including myself, have multiple student loans with different interest rates, so I made some `conditionalPanel`s that show up based on how many student loans the user says they have. Each `conditionalPanel` has `numericInput`s for loan principal, interest rate, and how much the user wants to pay per month. It's a bit of a process for the user to enter all this data once, and unfortunately it all gets wiped out if the user navigates away from the page or refreshes it.

How can I save the session data so the user doesn't have to re-enter their information in `numericInput`s every single time? I feel like the answer has something to do with accessing `session` data, but I'm not really sure. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here's an example of what goes on, on the UI side:

```
# Define UI for application
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Student Loan Calculator"),

# Sidebar with nested sidebar panels containing numeric inputs to enter info about each loan.
sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(width = '3',
             numericInput("numStuLoan",
                          "How many student loans do you have?",
                          min = 0,
                          max = 5,
                          value = 1,
                          step = 1),
             HTML("<br>"),
             #### #### #### #### ####
             #### Loan 1 ## #### ####
             #### #### #### #### ####
             conditionalPanel(condition="input.numStuLoan > 0",
                              HTML("<div align = 'left'><font size = '4'><b>1st Loan</b></font></div>"),
                              numericInput("loanPrin1",
                                           "Principal",
                                           min = 0,
                                           max = Inf,
                                           value = 10000,
                                           step = 50),

                              numericInput("loanInt1",
                                           "Interest Rate",
                                           min = 0.00,
                                           max = 20.00,
                                           value = 5.29,
                                           step = 0.1),

                              numericInput("monthPay1",
                                           "Monthly Payment",
                                           min = 0.00,
                                           max = Inf,
                                           value = 250,
                                           step = 1)),
             HTML("<br>"),
             ...
             ...
             ...
             {this code basically repeats for each loan}
```

Comment: There are several possibilities. First, did you take a look at bookmarking? https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/bookmarking-url.html Advantage: You dont have to change your code much. Disadvantage: The user has to keep a link. Second, what i used for that purpose is to save the client data in reactiveValues and reload that if necessary. Advantage: No link needed. Disadvantage: You might have to adjust your code. Third, I build an input logger: http://www.big-data-scientist.de/shiny/rstudio/sample-apps/ShinyInputLog/ where all inputs are saved (without variable amounts of inputs).

Comment: I'll take a look at bookmarking. Thanks!